# Is there a word for "songs whose lyrics don't match their tune"?

Tags: single-word-request

Songs in mind are those whose tunes don't quite reflect their lyrics. Such songs may have sad lyrics but uplifting tunes or vice versa. Where the "mood" of the lyrics don't quite match that of the tune.

The *ususal way* is that songs with upbeat tunes tend to have uplifting lyrics and sad songs often have both sad-sounding tunes and lyrics that tell a sad story

Examples I can find include:

- Pumped Up Kicks by Foster the People;
- Semi-Charmed Life by Third Eye Blind

Is there a word for such songs?

Comment: Do you think you can demonstrate your "problem" by including the lyrics (or part of it) with a sound example, like written notes or a [youtube] link (even if that later might get deleted due to some copyright things)?

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Examples of such songs are provided in the post. It's just any song where the "mood" of the lyrics don't quite match that of the tune.

Comment: it is great to read that your musical knowledge is good enough to have everything explained by just naming two songs from two bands. Mine is much lesser thus the question stays unclear to me. Neither did you write down which mood you extract from mentioned examples nor what tune you catch. Mood and tune can both mean Stimmung, makes it hard for me what you really refer to: https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/Stimmung

Comment: Usually, songs with upbeat tunes tend to have uplifting lyrics, and sad songs often have both sad-sounding tunes and lyrics that tell a sad story. I'm thinking of any song where the tune and lyrics don't match like so, especially if the tune and lyrics are opposite, like happy tunes with sad lyrics.

Comment: Is there are word for this in the english language? I can't think of any. Likewise, I can't think of a german word for the "phenomenon" you describe.

Comment: @waka: I deny to need an english word for that to be able to find a german word. Because there are some german expressions that lack english pendants and vice versa, examples: sturmfrei, Dreikäsehoch etc. from https://www.ef.com/wwen/blog/language/17-german-words-with-no-english-translation/ , or https://www.germanpod101.com/blog/2019/06/28/untranslatable-german-words/ personally I would have counted mutterseelenallein as well. The other way round there is "Sound" which I find it hard to have a german word that expresses all included in the english meaning.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm I am only wondering if such a word exists in english. Of course it may not help in finding a german word, but it might help with the research for such a word. For example, the Dreikäsehoch is a knee-high boy in english...

Comment: Why would this question be off-topic? Such a word doesn't exist as far as I know. But that doesn't make the Question off-topic.

Comment: @Olafant: I don't see off-topic, I see "unclear what is asked"

Comment: It was just closed. 3 of the votes were "off topic" which I disagree to, the other 2 (including mine) were "need clarity"

Comment: @ShegitBrahm As to why ask for an English word for it: If a word for that phenomenon does exist in the OP's mother tongue, that might explain why he thinks that a German word for that also exists.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf: In general to ask for the word in the questioner's mother tongue - yes, I agree. I usually don't assume mother tongue English if someone asks in english unless it is written in question or on it's profile.

Comment: FWIW, ELU had loads of single word requests like this one. They may not all be good, but no-one over there doubts that they are on-topic.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm I somehow **knew** I had answered in too few words - the part I did forbear to write was (...) OP's mother tongue, *which, concluding from his name, is probably English, even though it might also be Chinese*

Answer (score 3):

It's more than one word, but the first thing that immediantly comes to my mind.

In German I would say:

> Dissonanz zwischen Musik und Text

(Dissonanz in its meaning as Unstimmigkeit = discrepancy)

Answer (score 3):

There is a German term which refers to the gaping of information between images shown and the spoken text in programs such as news programs, documentaries or instructional films. It's [called](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ton-Bild-Schere)

> Ton-Bild-Schere (sound-image-scissors)

So in your case ... why not one of these

> Ton-Text-Schere
>
> Musik-Text-Schere

or similar constructions.

Answer (score 1):

Da gibt es eine Reihe von Möglichkeiten:

- ein fröhliches Lied mit traurigem Text
- eine traurige Melodie mit lustigem Text
- ein einfaches Lied mit anspruchsvollem Text
- ein musikalisch anspruchsvolles Lied mit simplem Text

und so weiter. Einen gängigen Ausdruck, um alle derartigen Varianten abzudecken, gibt es nicht. Man müsste einen erfinden, wie oben etwa Iris ("Dissonanz zwischen Musik und Text"), aber vermutlich müsste der Ausdruck noch weitere erklärende Zusätze tragen, wenn er auch selbsterklärend sein soll. Vielleicht:

> Lied mit atmosphärischem Kontrast zwischen Musik und Text
>
> Lied mit Stimmungs-Inkongruenz von Musik und Text
>
> Lied mit emotionaler Disparität von Musik und Text

wobei ich zugebe, dass dies nur für die emotionale Differenz ist, nicht für die andere Möglichkeit einer Komplexitätsdivergenz zwischen Text und Musik, die ich oben ja auch kurz erwähnt hatte.

Wenn man's in ein Adjektiv-Konstrukt packen will, könnte man vielleicht sagen:

> Text-Musik-disparates Lied

aber auch das wäre vermutlich dem uneingeweihten Leser nicht ohne Weiteres verständlich.